# Pandas pivoting on timestap table returns unexpected result

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame  with two columns: `ts` (timestamp) and `n` (number)

timestamps begin at `2016-07-15`:

```
In [1]: d.head()
Out[1]:
                       ts   n
0 2016-07-15 00:04:09.444  12
1 2016-07-15 00:05:01.633  12
2 2016-07-15 00:05:03.173  31
3 2016-07-15 00:05:03.970  12
4 2016-07-15 00:05:04.258  23
```

now, I pivot:

```
pd.pivot_table(d, columns='n', values='ts', aggfunc=lambda x: (np.min(x) - pd.Timestamp('2016-07-15')).days)
```

I expect to see column with integers represent days but instead I see:

```
n
12   1970-01-01
23   1970-01-01
31   1970-01-01
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What am O missing here? and is there a better way to achieve the same (trying to get the offset in days for the first appearance of `n` in the table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and add custom function with `apply`:

```
print (d.groupby('n')['ts'].apply(lambda x: (x.min() - pd.Timestamp('2016-07-15')).days))
n
12    0
23    0
31    0
Name: ts, dtype: int64
```

In your code you get `0` too, but values are converted to `datetime` (`1970-01-01`), because `dtype` of `ts` was `datetime` before.

I think then need cast `datetime` to `int`, but first convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
s = pd.pivot_table(d, columns='n', 
                      values='ts', 
                      aggfunc=lambda x: (np.min(x) - pd.Timestamp('2016-07-15')).days)
s = s.values.astype(int)
print (s)
n
12    0
23    0
31    0
Name: ts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks !! groupby  seems to be a better alternative to pivot!